# What is the right collation to be for a PostgreSQL database which may be used in different languages?

Tags: database, postgresql, character-encoding, locale, collation

I have a database created by:

```
-- Database: adatabase

-- DROP DATABASE adatabase;

CREATE DATABASE adatabase
  WITH OWNER = adatabaseowner
       ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

These appear to be the default in my PostgreSQL 8.4 installation, which appear to be based on the default locale my Ubuntu Installation was set to.

What are the appropriate settings I should use if I want to make the system multilingual in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least use UTF-8 for the encoding. With SQL_ASCII you can't store non-english characters (e.g. french accented characters, german umlauts).

If you upgrade to 9.1 the collation can be defined "on-the-fly" either in the query (`ORDER BY ... COLLATE ...`) or on a per column basis.